# Integrating a function over another integral in R

Tags: r, integral

I'm trying to numerically evaluate the following expression using R:

[image: expression]

The values of `t2`, `t3`, and `mu` are taken as constants, which are passed to my code from a larger function that's wrapped around it. Here's what I've got currently:

```
v4_conc_pt1 = integrate(Vectorize(function(y){
  ((exp(-y))/(1 - exp(-t2)))*(integrate(Vectorize(function(x){
    (1 - exp(-mu*(t2 - y + x)))*((exp(-x))/(1 - exp(-t3)))
  }), 0, t2))
}), 0, t3)
```

When I run this it returns the following error:

```
Error in ((exp(-y))/(1 - exp(-t2))) * (integrate(Vectorize(function(x) { : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

I have been trying to get this to work for a while now, and I'm at a loss. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Have a look at [the documentation for `integrate`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.5.3/topics/integrate). It returns a `list`, not a numeric, which is your error. `integrate(...)$value` would pull out the numeric result.

Comment: Wow, I feel pretty stupid for not catching that myself. It works now - thank you.